# My system is breached. What can I do?

Tags: hackmud

My system has been breached (by myself) and now it always give me the warning on the side of the screen and also when I do sys.status.

What can I do to get my system secured once again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wait until your system locks are rotated. It happens after some period of time. You can't make it happen faster.